# Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (12,)

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I'm try to create LSTM model. My data shape (23931, 7). 
I've choose two column for my model title['Train'] and title['Label']. 
I was following two tutorial
Here's [a link](https://medium.com/@shivambansal36/language-modelling-text-generation-using-lstms-deep-learning-for-nlp-ed36b224b275), 
[a link](https://towardsdatascience.com/machine-learning-word-embedding-sentiment-classification-using-keras-b83c28087456).

Please, help me to understand why this won't work.

When i run it i get the following error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (12,)
```

X_train_pad.shape (2839, 24) t_train_pad.shape(2839, 24, 14968)

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import gensim,logging
from nltk import word_tokenize
import string
import re

from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Embedding, LSTM, GRU, Dropout
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding
from keras.models import model_from_yaml
from keras.utils import plot_model, to_categorical
from IPython.display import SVG
from keras.utils.vis_utils import model_to_dot

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)
title = pd.read_excel('../file_name.xlsx')

x_train = title.loc[:2838,'Train']
y_train = title.loc[:2838,'Label']

x_test = title.loc[2839:,'Train']
y_test = title.loc[2839:,'Label']
x_train = x_train.apply(clean_text)
x_train = x_train.apply(word_tokenize)

def clean_text(text):
    text = text.lower()
    text = text.translate(string.punctuation)
    text = text.strip()
    text = re.sub(r'[?|!|\'|"|#]',r'',text)
    text = re.sub(r'[.|,|)|(|\|/]',r' ',text)
    return text

x_train = x_train.apply(clean_text)
x_train = x_train.apply(word_tokenize)

x_test = x_test.apply(clean_text)
x_test = x_test.apply(word_tokenize)

y_train = y_train.apply(clean_text)
y_train = y_train.apply(word_tokenize)

tockenizer = Tokenizer()
max_length = max([len(s.split()) for s in title['Название АСНА']])
tockenizer.fit_on_texts(title['Название АСНА'])
vocab_size = len(tockenizer.word_index) + 1

X_train_tokens = tockenizer.texts_to_sequences(x_train)
X_test_tokens = tockenizer.texts_to_sequences(x_test)

X_train_pad = pad_sequences(X_train_tokens, maxlen = max_length, padding='post')
X_test_pad = pad_sequences(X_test_tokens, maxlen = max_length, padding='post')

y_train_tokens = tockenizer.texts_to_sequences(y_train)
y_train_pad = pad_sequences(y_train_tokens, maxlen = max_length, padding='post')
y_train_label = to_categorical(y_train_pad, num_classes=vocab_size)

model = Sequential()
model.add( Embedding(vocab_size,EMBEDDING_DIM, input_length=max_length))
model.add(LSTM(256))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(vocab_size, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
print('Train...')
model.fit(X_train_pad, y_train_pad, batch_size=128, epochs=100, verbose=2)
```

Comment: you have a mismatch dimensions for the output, your target (y_train) has shape (1,) but your last layer (dense) has an output of shape (12,). check the dimensions to make sure you did not make a typo or a small mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` loss, then you need to provide integer labels (not one-hot encoded ones). Since you are already one-hot encoding your labels, you should use the `categorical_crossentropy` loss instead:

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
```